# editing a google form response and data lost

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I have created a standard google form and added a record.  i have set options to  edit the response . one of the questions i have added  allows me to jump straight to submit or continue editing .

However When i am editing a response and i choose the my option to jump to submit and then press submit , i find the information is lost when i go back to edit the response.

However if i scroll through all my answers and submit at the end, then the data is saved.

Is there an issue with google forms ? i am not using any scripts - it is standard editing and form options.

Comment: This is a serious bug in Google Form. We are facing this issue and lost lot of data when we delinked the form and try to take it to new place. We should have known this bug earlier and would not have used google form in this manner

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Google Forms when editing responses and changing the "go to" path from the initial submission. I've opened a question with a Google "Community Specialist" in the Google Help forums but so far she has not identified how to avoid this problem nor reported escalating it to get it fixed.

For those curious what to avoid, here is the scenario that causes a form to lose data:

- Create a form with multiple Go To paths
- Fill out a response using one Go To path of questions
- Submit response
- Click Edit Response
- Choose an option that takes you down a different Go To path of questions
- Submit the edited response
- Click Edit Response
- Going back to the original option Go To path, the earlier submitted data ***will now be gone***.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/a/dpsk12.net/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdB-czK9nzo9ix5o08Xn3_ARC06KiBvZFKOdvD0z8hxk9geNA/viewform) is a form I've created that demonstrates the issue.

[Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/ePNygKTuXWE/TJPXlyKwAQAJ) is the thread that as of this writing the Google Community Specialist has not yet solved. Perhaps if more people were to comment that it really is an issue she will pay more attention to it and bring it to the attention of who might be able to fix it.